# SUM numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 by using loop in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I NEED TO SUM  numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` by using loop in 8086 assembly. Here my attempt:

```
    MOV AX,01h
    MOV CX,0ah
LABEL1:
    inc AX
    LOOP LABEL1
    HLT
```

Comment: Please provide a clear question

Comment: instead of ` MOV AX,01h` I would have ` MOV AX,00h` and instead of `inc AX` I would use `ADD AX,CX` ...

Comment: I DID AND I GOD AX = 37 BUT THE RIGHT ANSWER IS 55

Comment: @over and how are you printing the result in AX ? maybe the problem is there (we do not see that part of code)....Also you use `HLT` ... I would expect `RET` to return from a program or subroutine ....

Comment: 37H = 55 decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a *container* of some kind to store your sum into. You can choose the register `DX` for that.

First make sure to empty this register **before** starting the loop.
Then on each iteration of the loop you `add` the current value of `AX` to this register `DX`.

```
    mov     ax, 1
    mov     cx, 10
    xor     dx, dx    ;This puts zero in DX
Label1:
    add     dx, ax    ;This adds int turn 1, 2, 3, ... ,10 to DX
    inc     ax
    loop    Label1
```

Not sure if you're *required* to use the `loop` instruction, but an alternative loop uses `AX` for its loop control.

```
    mov     ax, 1
    cwd               ;This puts zero in DX because AX holds a positive number
Label1:
    add     dx, ax    ;This adds in turn 1, 2, 3, ... ,10 to DX
    inc     ax
    cmp     ax, 10
    jbe     Label1
```

A somewhat better loop adds the numbers from high to low. This way the `cmp` instruction is no longer needed.

```
    mov     ax, 10
    cwd               ;This puts zero in DX because AX holds a positive number
Label1:
    add     dx, ax    ;This adds in turn 10, 9, 8, ... ,1 to DX
    dec     ax
    jnz     Label1
```

Comment: @over Both my loops will give 55 (decimal) as their result. Most probably the debugger that you use is displaying the result in **hexadecimal** where decimal 55 is shown as hexadecimal 37. (**3** x 16 + **7**)